# Display email as plain-text/HTML depending on sender?

Tags: email, conditional-formatting, microsoft-outlook-2016

For security reasons, I use the "Read all standard mail in plain text" option by default:

[image: Setting in TrustCenter]

And I then have to change to the HTML display on incoming emails (which are first displayed as plain text only.)

[image: Change Display]

This is very useful, but it can be annoying to need to do this for each and every mail I receive from *trusted sources*.

### Is there a way to configuer Outlook such that I have this behavior as default, but emails from white-listed sources show up a HTML ?

Current Outlook version in use:
`Version 1803 (build 9126.2295)`

Comment: If worried about security, you do know that these trusted sources can easily be spoofed?

Comment: @harrymc Sure. there is always a way around any kind of protective measure. It's a question on finding the "balance" between "security" and "convenience" in the daily workflow.

Comment: Current email clients are pretty savvy about security. I wouldn't worry too much.

Comment: Outlook doesn't provide an option for this. The setting to change the message format is a global setting, no option to configure this for specific senders. Just having an odd idea, you may try using the Junk folder which converts all standard emails to Plain Text format. Create rules to move all emails under the Junk folder with exceptions to specific senders. Just a thought, it might be not practicable.

Comment: @SteveFan Interesting idea. Possibly not practicble for me (-I'll continue re-enabling HTML for all my wanted emails manually then-), though. But thangs for confirming there is no setting I could use. At least I can stop searching for one. If you know that for a fact, can you type it as answer? I could then accept and declare this as closed.

Comment: Glad to do that :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Outlook doesn't provide an option for this. The setting to change the message format is a global setting, no option to configure this for specific senders.